# Bouncing clips out of Pro Tools

Tags: pro-tools

I have a handheld recorder that i record sound effects, atmospheres and concerts with. 
The recorded files is imported into Pro Tools, and all the good parts of a recording is clipped out with fades.
After clipping out the good parts, normalizing and adding some overall EQ/Limiting processing to the master track, i want to bounce each clip with the processing of the master track applied.

How would you solve the problem of getting each clip out of pro tools as wav files with the processing and fades applied?
I could choose each clip with the mouse and bounce it but that takes alot of time.

Thank you in advance!

Johan

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this more often you could write a script e.g. with AutoHotkey. That would make the workflow much faster. Also, the programming part is very easy.

Here is an example:

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Ill check it out! Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I have been experimenting a bit with Cubase and Nuendo. Both seems to have a solution to this problem. What i did was cut out the good parts of the one recorded track, add some EQ and then choose "Render in place" with the following settings. That way my impacts are named "impact 1,2,3...etc" And exported with or without the channel/master processing. Works like a charm in Nuendo especially.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not what you're wanting to hear, but this isn't possible with the current version of Pro Tools.

The method I tend to use is to duplicate and then consolidate the clip and then export in the clip list. But if you want the processing from the track or master then you will sadly have to sit bouncing files out all day! You could also try bouncing internally but this could either be just as (if not more) time consuming or a routing nightmare.

This is a feature that Pro Tools is in desperate need of.

I've heard reaper has the ability to batch export but have never personally looked into it. It might be wise to look into this next time you need to bounce multiple files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since i never found any solution to my problem in Pro Tools ive used Reaper instead before. Because of the ability in Reaper to batch export tracks. It seems i have to continue doing so. I think it is really odd that pro tools dont have support for this. Is this not something sound designers and post production houses could use a lot? I wonder if this possibillity is found in Cubase/Nuendo, i have thought about buying Nuendo now while there is a crossgrade campaign.

Comment: Yes, I use this all the time for games sound design and usually just bite the bullet and spend the time exporting them. I think the Pro Tools devs don't like the idea of you exporting your tracks and taking them into another DAW which happens a lot when recording music. As for other DAWS you'll have to shop around to find something that can batch export

Comment: Ah, thats great with Reaper. I guess all DAWs are good at different things. I use Pro Tools mainly to mix music for practice. I love the minimal approach, but sometimes i really miss functions like batch export.